# Too many identical PHP session files created for the same visitor, why?

Tags: php, session

While saving and reading session variables works fine, as expected, when I browse the file system on the server, I see lots of `sess_XXXXXXXXXXXXX` files being created for a single visitor (myself). To exclude the possibility that these are created by bots or other people, I added the following line to the code:

```
$_SESSION['IP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

The session files contain the same IP.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: may be browser cookies are disabled..

Comment: Cookies in general are enabled. 3rd party cookies are disabled. Could disabled 3rd party cookies cause this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server monitoring software was causing the problem, sending a new request every X minutes. HTTP sensor probably doesn't accept cookies. User agent string revealed the problem:

```
$_SESSION['IP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // DEBUG
$_SESSION['UA'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // DEBUG
```